# FireStore chatting structure

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chat

l am try to build angular rental app using angular2fire firestore for database . My app is working fine . But l am facing problem with structure of nodes uid chat . The idea of chatting is when user see specific ads rental and he would like to chatting with owner of ads rental for discussing .  l have attached images below to clarify what l mean .

[Ads rental detail with button chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKA88.jpg)

[chatting window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFQYr.jpg)

[database structure when user start chatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxmBp.jpg)

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sD97.jpg)

Now , l am getting only user sender chat and user receiver he can not see any message . l am looking for a good database structure to create room chating for any rental ads and only user sender and user receiver can access to that room and see messages  .

Comment: What have you tried doing to fix it?

Comment: l fixed by created room . That room content on name of ads rent and description  . Also uid of user sender and receiver to showing the room for them only .